# Code Review and Farm Governance plan review Guidelines for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

One of our clients have a SharePoint 2010 application. This application is accessible over the Intranet and Extranet.

I am required to perform Code Review of the custom web parts and Workflows they have developed and
also perform a review of their governance plan (disk space, backup, recovery etc.)

Does anyone has a checklist or guidelines reference that I can use to accomplish this task?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code review tool
[SharePoint Software Factory](https://spsf.codeplex.com/)

Here are some suggestions of SharePoint governance plans:
[Intranet Governance Plan](http://www.sharesquared.com/Documents/ShareSquared_Sample_Intranet_Governance_Plan.pdf)

http://www.thesharepointdude.com/governance-rules/

http://office.microsoft.com/download/afile.aspx?AssetID=AM102310201033